# como fazer um contador dos itens do carrinho

Tags: php

eu quero que ele pegue minha session carrinho e veja quantos produtos tem ai ele faz uma especie de for que vai rodar enquanto tiver produtos no carrinho, mais especifico ele vai rodar pela quantidade do carrinho se eu comprar 3 produtos ele vai rodar 3x e assim por diante e quero pegar essa variavel `$i` e adicionar conforme os numeros do pagseguro ex o pagseguro denomina o nome dos itens assim

```
<input name="itemId1" type="hidden" value="id_produto">
```

aonde esta esse name itemId1 ele tem que contar fica tipo assim:

```
<input name="itemId<?php echo $i; ?>" type="hidden" value="id_produto">
```

eu fiz mais ou menos assim e ele acaba entrando em loop infinito e dando pau no navegador alguem pode me ajudar?

o nome da minha session e  `SESSION['carrinho']`.

aqui e onde eu crio e faco as acoes para ele de add, deleta etc

```
session_start();

      if(!isset($_SESSION['carrinho'])){
         $_SESSION['carrinho'] = array();
      }

      //adiciona produto

      if(isset($_GET['acao'])){

         //ADICIONAR CARRINHO
         if($_GET['acao'] == 'add'){
            $id = intval($_GET['id']);
            if(!isset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$id])){
               $_SESSION['carrinho'][$id] = 1;
            }else{
               $_SESSION['carrinho'][$id] += 1;
            }
         }

         //REMOVER CARRINHO
         if($_GET['acao'] == 'del'){
            $id = intval($_GET['id']);
            if(isset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$id])){
               unset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$id]);
            }
         }

         //ALTERAR QUANTIDADE
         if($_GET['acao'] == 'up'){
            if(is_array($_POST['prod'])){
               foreach($_POST['prod'] as $id => $qtd){
                  $id  = intval($id);
                  $qtd = intval($qtd);
                  if(!empty($qtd) || $qtd <> 0){
                     $_SESSION['carrinho'][$id] = $qtd;
                  }else{
                     unset($_SESSION['carrinho'][$id]);
                  }
               }
            }
         }

      }
```

essa parte e o foreach dele

```
foreach($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $id => $qtd){
                              $sql   = "SELECT *  FROM produtos WHERE id_produto= '$id'";
                              $qr    = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                              $ln    = mysql_fetch_assoc($qr);

                              $nome  = $ln['nome'];
                              $preco = $ln['preco'];
                              $sub   = $ln['preco'] * $qtd;
                              $img   = $ln['img'];
                              $desc  = $ln['descricao'];
                              $id    = $ln['id_produto']; 
                              $total += $ln['preco'] * $qtd;
```

e aqui foi o que eu tentei fazer

```
<form target="pagseguro" method="post" action="https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/checkout/checkout.jhtml">
          <input type="hidden" name="email_cobranca" value="suporte@loja.com.br">
          <input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="CP">
          <input type="hidden" name="moeda" value="BRL">
         <?php 
            for($i = 1; count($_SESSION['carrinho']) > 0; $i++){
         ?>
        <input name="itemId<?php echo $i; ?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id[$i]; ?>">  
        <input name="itemDescription<?echo $i; ?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $nome[$i]; ?>">  
        <input name="itemAmount<?php echo $i; ?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $sub[$i];?>">  
        <input id="leo" name="itemQuantity<?php echo $i; ?>" type="hidden" value="1">  
        <input name="itemWeight<?php echo $i; ?>" type="hidden" value="1000">


          <button  class="btn btn-default check_out" id="comprar">Finalizar Compra</button>
          <?php } ?>
        </form>
```

Comment: Poste o código do teu carrinho e a forma como ele é armazenado na sessão.

Comment: ja editei da uma olhada e ve se voce pode me ajudar

Comment: 1 item a cada vez ?

Comment: como assim 1 item a cada vez? tipo eu tenho o carrinho pronto como postei o codigo ai so que quando mando pro pagseguro ele pega so 1 ai eu li na documentacao que se voce colocar outros inputs hiden com o numero 2 serao como eu posso dizer o segundo produto a ser add. mas desse jeito eu tentei fazer e ele sempre repete o primeiro produto entao queria fazer mais dinamico como estou tentando fazer agora com o foreach ou o for mas nao estou conseguindo esta dando carrinho vazio.

Answer (score 0):

Altere:

```
for($i = 1; count($_SESSION['carrinho']) > 0; $i++){
```

Para:

```
for($i = 1; $i<=count($_SESSION['carrinho']); $i++){
```

Dessa forma, enquanto ele for menor ou igual a contagem do carrinho, fará o loop.

Comment: aqui tambem continua com o mesmo erro que o meu da carrinho vazio

Answer (score -1):

Faz assim:

```
<form target="pagseguro" method="post" action="https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/checkout/checkout.jhtml">
<input type="hidden" name="email_cobranca" value="suporte@loja.com.br">
<input type="hidden" name="tipo" value="CP">
<input type="hidden" name="moeda" value="BRL">
<?php 
if($_SESSION['carrinho']){
foreach ($_SESSION['carrinho'] as $key => $value){    
?>
    <input name="itemId<?php echo $key; ?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>">  
    <input name="itemDescription<?echo $key; ?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $value['nome']; ?>">  
    <input name="itemAmount<?php echo $key; ?>" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $value['sub'];?>">  
    <input id="leo" name="itemQuantity<?php echo $key; ?>" type="hidden" value="1">  
    <input name="itemWeight<?php echo $key; ?>" type="hidden" value="1000">
<?php } ?>

<button  class="btn btn-default check_out" id="comprar">Finalizar Compra</button>
<?php } ?>
</form>
```

Comment: ele da error no pagseguro que o carrinho esta vazio